# how to display a table of 2 rows and 1 column on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a table a table of 2 rows and 1 column on clicking the notifications button tab contained in the list tag . how can i do this?

Comment: Read : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

first, create your table with html, second, give it a "hidden" css property, and add some javascript.

HTML:

```
<table id="testTable">
 <tr>
   <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>test</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#testTable{
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("yourNotificationElement").onclick = function() {displayTable()};
function displayTable() {
 document.getElementById("testTable").style.display= "inline";
}
```